# Using yield in Python?

Tags: python, generator, yield

I have this code:

```
def generator(n):
    list_of = range(1,n+1)
    for i in list_of:
        if i % 7 == 0:
            yield i

print generator(100)
```

This should print all the numbers in the given range that are divisible by `7`, but the output is `<generator object generator at 0x1004ad280>` instead.

Also, the word `yield` in my text editor (KOD) doesn't appear highlighted in sky blue color like all the reserved words but instead appears in white, is that fine?

Comment: It's bug/misfeature in your text editors syntax highlighting.

Comment: You may also want to have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/231767/1025391

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your generator **works**. You forgot to iterate over it though:

```
for elem in generator(100):
    print elem
```

or you could turn it into a list:

```
print list(generator(100))
```

You instead printed the generator object produced by calling the generator function. A generator function produces a *suspended* generator. Only when you iterate over it is code executed (until the next `yield`).

Demo:

```
>>> def generator(n):
...     list_of = range(1,n+1)
...     for i in list_of:
...         if i % 7 == 0:
...             yield i
... 
>>> print list(generator(100))
[7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63, 70, 77, 84, 91, 98]
```

The `list()` call iterates over the given argument, producing a Python list object with all elements yielded by the argument. Great for iterating over a generator to pull in all the elements that it produces.

As for KOD; that editor hasn't seen updates in years now; you may want to switch to something else. As the [KOD twitter feed stated *2 years ago*](https://twitter.com/kod_app/status/202591080405929984):

> Don't wait for me, I'm kind of like a Zombie. Go get Sublime Text [@sublimehq](https://twitter.com/sublimehq) which is awesome: http://www.sublimetext.com

I concur; Sublime Text is my current editor of choice.

Answer (score 3):

Generators functions allow you to declare a function that behaves like an iterator, i.e. it can be used in a for loop. u can learn Here:[generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Generators)

```
def generator(n):
        list_of = range(1,n+1)
        for i in list_of:
            if i % 7 == 0:
                yield i

    for i in generator(100):
        print i
```

or

You can use `next(generator(100))` to print one element at top

or

```
list(generator(100))
```

Answer (score 2):

When calling the generator function you receive generator object. In order to get values you should iterate over this object. In you case you can do `list(generator(100))`

But this doesn't make sense. Use list comprehension if you need list:

```
[x for x in range(1, 101) if x % 7 == 0]
```